# When to use RestRequest/RestResponse and when to use HttpResuest/HttpResponse?

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, apex-code

When to use RestRequest/RestResponse and when to use HttpResuest/HttpResponse?

I am learning REST in Saleforce. I know there are methods like GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
But having confusion in these both and can I use Http request/Http Response instead of RestRequest/Restresponse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestRequest/RestResponse are custom functions that allow you to listen for outside REST API requests from Apex code. You define a `@RestResource` annotated class and it functions much like the built in SF Rest API (although with the logic that you define). The different HTTP methods you mention are meant to respond (at a specific path) to different types of outside requests. A REST `GET` method should get a record. SF already has a REST API that follows these rules. They just enable you to write the logic to get the record (in this example) yourself, should you have some custom logic you wish to implement. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) is a link to the MDN docs that describe the different HTTP methods.

An HTTP request/response is when you wish to, from inside your APEX code, make a callout to some resource *outside* of SF.

In other words, think of `RestRequest/RestResponse` as a server method and `HTTP` as a client method.